# Unable to set values to arrays in a class

Tags: c#

I am unable to set values to arrays that I declared inside a class. 
Its probably something simple that I am not doing.

```
using System.IO;    
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public void Button1()
{
   Data.species.SetValue("none", 1);

   // also tried
   Data.species[1] = "something";
}

[System.Serializable] 
public class Data
{
   public string[] species = new string[101];
   public string[] name = new string[101];
   public int[] startlvl = new int[101];
}
```

Comment: You need to instantiate you class as 
in `var data = new Data(); data.species[1] = "something"`

Comment: Or make the variables  and or class static...

Comment: Q: Where in your code have you declared an *instance* of "Data".  For example: `Data myData = new Data(); myData.species[0] = "something";`

Comment: Any time you get an error in your code it's important to [tell us the error](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Answer (score -1):

You should do one of 2 things: either declare the fields as static, or create an instance of your class. Also, make sure that your `Button1` is itself inside a class (it doesn't seem this way from the code that you posted here).

1. Static fields:

```
public void Button1()
{
    Data.species[1] = "something";
}

[System.Serializable] 
public class Data
{
    public static string[] species = new string[101];
    public static string[] name = new string[101];
    public static int[] startlvl = new int[101];
}
```

2. Class instance:

```
public void Button1()
{
    var data = new Data();
    data.species[1] = "something";
}

[System.Serializable] 
public class Data
{
    public string[] species = new string[101];
    public string[] name = new string[101];
    public int[] startlvl = new int[101];
}
```

Comment: This worked      data.species[1] = "something";        but I am not sure how to send that information back into the Data class.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure what you mean by "send that information back into the Data class". If you want to execute some logic inside the `Data` class when a value is set on one of the arrays, then you should use a property or an indexer.

Comment: I got everything working now, thanks for your help.